# how can I access the Name field of item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutItems}" x:Name="ItemsOnGrid" View="{StaticResource ImageDetailView}" SelectionMode="Multiple">

    </ListView>
```

C#

```
        foreach (var item in ItemsOnGrid.SelectedItems)
        {
            string sourceFile = path + @"\" + item;
            string destFile = @"H:\Desktop";
            if (Directory.Exists(@"H:\Desktop"))
            {
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }
        }
```

Although I have items selected in my ListView, when I enter the foreach loop, I can't figure out how to get the Name field of item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you cast the `item` variable to the type of element you are providing as `ItemsSource`. It looks that that should be something like `ShortcutItem`? By WPF design, there is no way to strongly type the `ItemsSource` property.

```
foreach (ShortcutItem item in ItemsOnGrid.SelectedItems) {
     string name = item.Name;
}
```